# Merge dictionaries with same key from two lists of dicts in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, as below. Both dictionaries have a list of dictionaries as the value associated with their `properties` key; each dictionary within these lists has an `id` key. I wish to merge my two dictionaries into one such that the `properties` list in the resulting dictionary only has one dictionary for each `id`.

```
{
   "name":"harry",
   "properties":[
      {
         "id":"N3",
         "status":"OPEN",
         "type":"energetic"
      },
      {
         "id":"N5",
         "status":"OPEN",
         "type":"hot"
      }
   ]
}
```

and the other list:

```
{
   "name":"harry",
   "properties":[
      {
         "id":"N3",
         "type":"energetic",
         "language": "english"
      },
      {
         "id":"N6",
         "status":"OPEN",
         "type":"cool"
      }
   ]
}
```

The output I am trying to achieve is:

```
   "name":"harry",
   "properties":[
      {
         "id":"N3",
         "status":"OPEN",
         "type":"energetic",
         "language": "english"
      },
      {
         "id":"N5",
         "status":"OPEN",
         "type":"hot"
      },
      {
         "id":"N6",
         "status":"OPEN",
         "type":"cool"
      }
   ]
}
```

As `id: N3` is common in both the lists, those 2 dicts should be merged with all the fields. So far I have tried using `itertools` and

```
ds = [d1, d2]
d = {}
for k in d1.keys():
  d[k] = tuple(d[k] for d in ds)
```

Could someone please help in figuring this out?

Comment: @AlexWaygood My Bad. I am so sorry. its two dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the approach:

```
a = {
   "name":"harry",
   "properties":[
      {
         "id":"N3",
         "status":"OPEN",
         "type":"energetic"
      },
      {
         "id":"N5",
         "status":"OPEN",
         "type":"hot"
      }
   ]
}
b = {
   "name":"harry",
   "properties":[
      {
         "id":"N3",
         "type":"energetic",
         "language": "english"
      },
      {
         "id":"N6",
         "status":"OPEN",
         "type":"cool"
      }
   ]
}

# Create dic maintaining the index of each id in resp dict
a_ids = {item['id']: index for index,item in enumerate(a['properties'])} #{'N3': 0, 'N5': 1}
b_ids = {item['id']: index for index,item in enumerate(b['properties'])} #{'N3': 0, 'N6': 1}

# Loop through one of the dict created
for id in a_ids.keys():
    # If same ID exists in another dict, update it with the key value
    if id in b_ids:
        b['properties'][b_ids[id]].update(a['properties'][a_ids[id]])
    # If it does not exist, then just append the new dict
    else:
        b['properties'].append(a['properties'][a_ids[id]])
        
        
print (b)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'harry', 'properties': [{'id': 'N3', 'type': 'energetic', 'language': 'english', 'status': 'OPEN'}, {'id': 'N6', 'status': 'OPEN', 'type': 'cool'}, {'id': 'N5', 'status': 'OPEN', 'type': 'hot'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help to treat the two objects as elements each in their own lists. Maybe you have other objects with different `name` values, such as might come out of a JSON-formatted REST request.

Then you could do a [left outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join) on both `name` and `id` keys:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

a = [
    {
        "name": "harry",
        "properties": [
            {
                "id":"N3",
                "status":"OPEN",
                "type":"energetic"
            },
            {
                "id":"N5",
                "status":"OPEN",
                "type":"hot"
            }
        ]
    }
]

b = [
    {
        "name": "harry",
        "properties": [
            {
                "id":"N3",
                "type":"energetic",
                "language": "english"
            },
            {
                "id":"N6",
                "status":"OPEN",
                "type":"cool"
            }
        ]
    }
]

a_names = set()
a_prop_ids_by_name = {}
a_by_name = {}
for ao in a:
    an = ao['name']
    a_names.add(an)
    if an not in a_prop_ids_by_name:
        a_prop_ids_by_name[an] = set()
    for ap in ao['properties']:
        api = ap['id']
        a_prop_ids_by_name[an].add(api)
    a_by_name[an] = ao

res = []

for bo in b:
    bn = bo['name']
    if bn not in a_names:
        res.append(bo)
    else:
        ao = a_by_name[bn]
        bp = bo['properties']
        for bpo in bp:
             if bpo['id'] not in a_prop_ids_by_name[bn]:
                 ao['properties'].append(bpo)
        res.append(ao)

print(res)
```

The idea above is to process list `a` for names and ids. The names and ids-by-name are instances of a Python `set`. So members are always unique.

Once you have these sets, you can do the left outer join on the contents of list `b`.

Either there's an object in `b` that doesn't exist in `a` (i.e. shares a common `name`), in which case you add that object to the result as-is. But if there is an object in `b` that does exist in `a` (which shares a common `name`), then you iterate over that object's `id` values and look for ids not already in the `a` ids-by-name set. You add missing properties to `a`, and then add that processed object to the result.

Output:

```
[{'name': 'harry', 'properties': [{'id': 'N3', 'status': 'OPEN', 'type': 'energetic'}, {'id': 'N5', 'status': 'OPEN', 'type': 'hot'}, {'id': 'N6', 'status': 'OPEN', 'type': 'cool'}]}]
```

This doesn't do any error checking on input. This relies on `name` values being unique per object. So if you have duplicate keys in objects in both lists, you may get garbage (incorrect or unexpected output).